# How can I clone a gene into a plasmid vector with an N-terminal his tag and TEV cleavage site between the tag and the start of the sequence?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, proteins, lab-techniques, biotechnology

I'm a scientist who has significant experience in chemistry but am relatively new to molecular biology and biochemical techniques. I'm trying to make an isolated domain of a protein (166 residues, 19.5 kDa) with an N-terminal His tag and a TEV cleavage site between the His tag and the N-terminus of the domain. The purpose is to study the properties of the domain in isolation, but without any tags that might interfere with its function. Using the His-tag will make for easy purification, after which the tag can be removed with TEV protease, leaving only a glycine at the N-terminus of the domain, which will not affect my experiments in an appreciable way.

The way I've gone about doing this is to use a forward primer that, after the restriction site and start codon, contains the sequence which codes for the his tag followed by the TEV cleavage sequence, followed by the first 6 codons of the domain sequence. The reverse primer contains the final 6 codons of the domain sequence followed by a stop codon and restriction site. These primers are used to amplify the target domain sequence from a plasmid that contains the full protein sequence, but with the N-terminal cleavable tag attached. The plan is then to clone this DNA insert into a pET21b vector to transform into DH5alpha / BL21 cells.

However, it seems like I'm having problems during PCR amplifying the sequence of the domain from the template DNA. After cloning my purified PCR product into the pET21b vector, and successfully transforming into DH5a cells, sequencing the section of the cloned plasmid with the insert revealed that the insert DNA consisted of only the forward and reverse primer sequences on the ends, sandwiching a single alanine codon. Put another way, the inserted sequence reads as (His-tag)-(TEV cleavage site)-(First 6 codons of domain)-(Single Ala Codon)-(Last 6 codons of domain). This would mean all my cloning steps were fine, but the insert DNA was copied incorrectly during PCR. If it were just the primer ends, I'd think there was some sort of overlap between the primer sequences, but there is that one alanine from the domain template DNA (alanine is the next residue after the first 6 in the domain sequence). A weird result, and I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting.

My question is, is there anything that I'm doing in this procedure that might stand out as particularly problematic that would cause this issue? Or more generally, is there a better way to put a TEV protease-cleavable his tag on the N-terminus of a protein? Any advice would help, even if it's just to point in the direction of useful references or protocols, and I'm happy to clarify as needed. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think your approach is problematic, I think it's just a  PCR technical issue. Have you run your PCR product on an agarose gel to check it ? How have you purified you PCR product : column, gel extract ? Can you add the primers sequences ? What I can envision so far is that your primers may have Tm to far apart.

Comment: I hadn't run a gel on it, but I used a Qiagen pcr cleanup kit (mini eppendorf column). The primer sequences are: Fwd: TAAGCAGAATTCATGCACCACCACCACCACCACGAAAACCTGTATTTTCAAGGCCTGGATTATAGACCAGTG
Rev (reverse complement, 5'->3'):TGCTTACTCGAGTTATACTGTTTTTGTGAAGTACAG

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please [edit] the above information into your post (comments are ephemeral and often overlooked — as such they should not be used to convey information important to understanding the question). ——— Note that you should always run a gel to check the size of PCR products — knowing the size (and number) of bands produced could be key to answering your question. In addition, it could be helpful for you to post the target (template) sequence — a (cryptic) primer binding site is one of many possible explanations for your result. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so if you haven't run a gel I would do that first and as mention by @tyersome you should always do it so you know what you're working with. In the meantime if you could share the target sequence it would help us check if there is something happening there. Thanks.